Error de mala detección de tipo de Input - ReactJS y TypeScript
El error que estoy teniendo consiste en que el input esta siendo detectado como si fuera para ingresar tarjetas de crédito, cuando en realidad esto no es así, mi input es para buscar usuarios registrados en mi plataforma según su nombre de usuario y como podrán ver en los ejemplos el código esta dictándole que debe ser de tipo 'text'.
desconozco realmente si estoy Omitiendo algún detalle declarativo o en mis funciones de seteo de data si estoy omitiendo algún detalle técnico.
Adjunto Imagen:

Adjunto Código del Componente del input:


import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { InputProps } from '@/components/models/atoms';
import styles from './style.module.scss';
import { ConditionProtector } from '../Protectors';
import { ButtonPrimary } from '@/components/atomic/atoms';

export const InputText = ({
    type = 'text',
    name,
    label,
    placeholder,
    value,
    onChange,
    containerClassName = '',
    labelClassName = '',
    inputClassName = '',
    buttonClassName = '',
    clickAddButton,
    isSearchButton = false,
    disabled = false,
    required = false,
    checked = false,
    controlId = '',
    errorMessage = '',
    defaultValue,
    ...rest
}: InputProps) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Form.Group className={`text-start form-group ${containerClassName}`} controlId={name}>
                <Form.Label className={labelClassName}>{label}</Form.Label>
                <div className='flex justify-evenly'>
                    <div className="relative w-full">
                        <Form.Control
                            className={`${styles.formInput} form-control ${inputClassName}`}
                            placeholder={placeholder}
                            name={name}
                            type={type}
                            value={value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required={required}
                            disabled={disabled}
                            defaultValue={defaultValue}
                            checked={checked}
                            autoComplete="off"
                            {...rest}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <ConditionProtector isShowed={isSearchButton === true}>
                        <ButtonPrimary
                            type='button'
                            classNameButton={buttonClassName}
                            isLoading={disabled}
                            clickButtonAction={clickAddButton}
                        >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id='figureSVG3' width="24" height="24" fill='white' viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z" />
                            </svg>
                        </ButtonPrimary>
                    </ConditionProtector>
                </div>
            </Form.Group>
        </>
    );
};



Adjunto Código del componente consumiendose:


import { toastOptions } from '@/components/utils';
import { useUser } from '@/context/UserContext';
import { claimWarranty, deleteWork, getService, getServices, getUser, getUsers } from '@/services';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { ButtonPrimary, InputText } from '@/components/atomic/atoms';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { getUnixNowDate } from '@/utils/getUnixNowDate';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { CardUser } from '@/components/atomic/molecules';

export const UsuariosTemplate = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { user, logout } = useUser();
    const [userSession, setUserSession] = useState<any>({
        userId: '',
        userName: 'user',
        userRole: 2
    });
    const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState<any>({});
    const [getData, setGetData] = useState<any>(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<any>(false);
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState<any>({
        nameUser: ''
    });
    const [presentDate, setPresentDate] = useState<any>(0);


    /**
     * Use Effects
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        setUserSession(user);
        getUsersData();
        setPresentDate(getUnixNowDate());
    }, [user]);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(usersData);
    }, [usersData]);

    /**
     * Functions
     */
    const getUsersData = async () => {
        try {
            await getUsers().then(({ status, error, message, data }) => {
                if (error === true) {
                    toast.error(`${message}`, toastOptions);
                } else {
                    setGetData(true);
                    setUsersData(data.users);
                }
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const trimmedValue = value.trim();
        setUserName({ ...userName, [name]: trimmedValue });
    };
    const handleClick = async () => {
        try {
            await getUser(userName.nameUser).then(({ status, error, message, data }) => {
                if (error === true) {
                    toast.error(`${message}`, toastOptions);
                } else {
                    setGetData(true)
                    setUsersData(data.users);
                }
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const handleClickBTN = () => {
        router.push('/agregar_usuario');
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center max-w-2xl md:mx-auto mx-8 relative">
                <div className="container m-4">
                    <div className="max-w-3xl w-full mx-auto grid gap-4 grid-cols-1">
                        <div className="flex flex-col top-14 z-10">
                            <ButtonPrimary
                                type='button'
                                clickButtonAction={handleClickBTN}
                            >
                                Agregar Usuario
                            </ButtonPrimary>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col sticky top-14 z-10">
                            <div className='w-full align-top mb-5'>
                                <InputText
                                    label="Nombre de Usuario"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Usuario"
                                    value={userName.nameUser}
                                    name="nameUser"
                                    labelClassName='block mb-2 text-md md:text-sm font-medium text-gray-900'
                                    inputClassName='
                                        bg-gradient-to-r from-white to-gray-100 
                                        rounded-l-lg p-4 w-full shadow-xl hover:shadow-md 
                                        transition duration-500
                                    '
                                    buttonClassName='
                                        bg-gradient-to-r from-[#98d443] to-[#78be58] 
                                        font-black rounded-r-lg text-center text-balance text-3xl align-text-top
                                        shadow-md hover:shadow-xl py-2 px-5
                                        hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-[#94ca8b] hover:to-[#80d060]
                                        transition duration-500
                                    '
                                    isSearchButton={true}
                                    clickAddButton={handleClick}
                                    disabled={isLoading === true ? true : false}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col">
                            {
                                getData === true &&
                                usersData.map((data: any) => (
                                    <div key={data._id}>
                                        <CardUser
                                            username={data.username}
                                            role={data.role}
                                            roleName={data.roleName}
                                            addedServices={data.addedServices}
                                            warrantyClaims={data.warrantyClaims}
                                            isActive={data.isActive}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}




¿Donde esta la lógica que define el mensaje de error que se debe mostrar según el tipo de input? Esta pregunta necesita más detalles

eso es lo extraño, no tengo logica para mostrar errores de tipo de input, esa alerta la tira directamente el navegador, a pesar de que no he colocado el tipo CreditCard o algo parecido.
